# Plotly subplot x axis not aligned

Tags: python, plotly, subplot, timeline

I have a plotly subplot with 6 charts: 1 timeline (plotly.express.timeline) and 5 scatter charts (plotly.graph_objects.Scatter) with shared x axes.

All the scatters x-axes are aligned with same origin and end points, but the timeline chart (converted from px to go) with:

```
for trace in self.farm_figs.data:
    self.figs.add_trace(trace, secondary_y=False, row=row, col=col)
```

is not aligned (see the image below):

[image: plotly subplot with px and go]

Code:

```
    def create_figs(self):
        self.figs = make_subplots(
            rows=6, cols=1,
            shared_xaxes=True, 
            specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}],[{"secondary_y": True}],[{"secondary_y": True}],[{"secondary_y": True}],[{"secondary_y": True}],[{"secondary_y": True}]]
            )        
        self.create_farm_fig(1, 1)
        
        self.create_temp_fig(3, 1)
        self.create_pcr_fig(4, 1)
        self.create_pct_fig(5, 1)
        self.create_wbc_fig(6, 1)
        self.create_events_fig(2, 1)
        #self.figs.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>primary</b> yaxis title", secondary_y=False)
        #self.figs.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>secondary</b> yaxis title", secondary_y=True)
        self.figs.layout.xaxis = self.farm_figs.layout.xaxis

    def create_farm_fig(self, row, col):
        self.farm_figs = px.timeline(
            self.get_farmaci_intervals(), 
            x_start="Start", 
            x_end="Finish", 
            y="Farmaci", 
            color="Farmaci",
            range_x=self.date_range,
            ) 
        for trace in self.farm_figs.data:
            self.figs.add_trace(trace, secondary_y=False, row=row, col=col) 
        
    def create_pcr_fig(self, row, col):
        self.pcr_fig = go.Scatter(
            x=self.misurazioni['data'], 
            y=self.misurazioni['pcr'], 
            mode='lines+markers', 
            name="PCR (mg/L)")
        self.figs.update_xaxes(range=self.date_range, nticks=self.dates, row=row, col=col)
        self.figs.add_trace(self.pcr_fig, secondary_y=False, row=row, col=col)       

    def create_pct_fig(self, row, col):
        self.pct_fig = go.Scatter(
            x=self.misurazioni['data'], 
            y=self.misurazioni['pct'], 
            mode='lines+markers', 
            name="PCT (mg/L)")
        self.figs.update_xaxes(range=self.date_range, nticks=self.dates, row=row, col=col)
        self.figs.add_trace(self.pct_fig, secondary_y=False, row=row, col=col)      

    def create_wbc_fig(self, row, col):
        self.wbc_fig = go.Scatter(
            x=self.misurazioni['data'], 
            y=self.misurazioni['wbc'], 
            mode='lines+markers', 
            name="WBC (x10^3 uL)")
        self.figs.update_xaxes(range=self.date_range, tick0=self.date_range[0], dtick='D2', row=row, col=col)
        self.figs.add_trace(self.wbc_fig, secondary_y=False, row=row, col=col)       

    def create_temp_fig(self, row, col):
        self.temp_fig = go.Scatter(
            x=self.misurazioni['data'], 
            y=self.misurazioni['temperatura'], 
            mode='lines+markers', 
            name="Temperature (°C)")
        self.figs.update_xaxes(range=self.date_range, nticks=self.dates, row=row, col=col)
        self.figs.add_trace(self.temp_fig, secondary_y=False, row=row, col=col)   

    def create_events_fig(self, row, col):
        self.events_figs = go.Scatter(
            x=self.eventi['data'],
            y=self.eventi['tipo'],
            text=self.eventi['note'],
            mode='markers',
            name="Eventi",
            textposition="top center",
            marker=dict(
                color='MediumPurple',
                size=20,
                #line=dict(color='MediumPurple', width=2)
            )
        )
        self.figs.update_xaxes(range=self.date_range, nticks=self.dates, row=2, col=1)
        self.figs.add_trace(self.events_figs, secondary_y=False, row=2, col=1)  

    def show(self):
        self.figs.show()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you have the beginning and end of your data to see if we can reproduce part of your plot?